# How to operate the EC2 instance from the computer without keypairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just started playing around with EC2, I created the keypairs and have no problems in my own laptop. But I just wonder how I can operate it from another computer.
Is that possible to send the keypair-file ,or simply export it from the AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states on the [EC2 Key pair page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html):

> Amazon EC2 doesn't keep a copy of your private key; therefore, if you lose your private key, there is no way to recover it. If you lose the private key for an instance store-backed instance, you can't access the instance; you should terminate the instance and launch another instance using a new key pair.

Thus you can't export it again from the AWS Console. You would have to transfer the original one you downloaded when you launched the instance.